# Сканирование сети Wifi на Android

Tags: android, kotlin, wifi

Каким образом можно получить информацию об устройствах, подключенных к wifi сети? Может есть какие-то библиотеки для этого? В данный момент получилось достать только общую информацию о сети.

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
                val success = intent.getBooleanExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_RESULTS_UPDATED, false)
                if (success) {
                    scanSuccess()
                } else {
                    scanFailure()
                }
            }
    
    but.setOnClickListener {
                if (checkWiFiAdapter()){
                    val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
                    intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)
                    this.registerReceiver(wifiScanReceiver, intentFilter)
    
                    val success = wifiManager.startScan()
                    if (!success) {
                        scanFailure()
                    }
                    scanSuccess()
                }
                else {
                    showMes("Enable WiFi")
                }
            }
    
    private fun scanSuccess() {
                try {
                    val results = wifiManager.scanResults
                    val Nw = wifiManager.connectionInfo
                    var info : String? = null
                    results.forEach(){
                        info += "${it.SSID}, ${it.BSSID}, ${it.level}, ${it.frequency}\n"
                    }
                    if (info != null) {
                        Log.i("mes", info)
                    }
                    Log.i("mes", Nw.toString())
                }
                catch (e:SecurityException){
                }
            }
```